# fill inputs google forms with vba excel function

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to fill in the google forms inputs but i am not getting,it fills, but not all fields

````
Public Sub ConectaWeb()
On Error Resume Next
Dim endereço As String
Dim mostra As Boolean

Dim i, n, x As Integer
endereço = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-d6XfqSS_-P2SCRiIJMKU477NPlzFnkjVHe0RqO2DMSc4xA/viewform"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate (endereço)
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
IE.Visible = True
IE.document.forms.Item(0).Item(2).Value = "Comentários / Sugestões"
IE.document.forms.Item(0).Item(3).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
IE.document.forms.Item(0).Item(4).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A2")
IE.document.forms.Item(0).Item(5).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A3")
IE.document.forms.Item(0).submit
   
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
End Sub ```
````

Comment: What fills, what doesn't?

Comment: inputs from google forms i want fill the inputs with vba code,did you enter the link?

Comment: No, your question isn't clear in what your problem is. You've stated *"...it fills, but not all fields"* - Please update your question to be clearer in *what* fills and *what* doesn't. Include which range references are working and which aren't etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to complete the inputs

```
Public Sub ConectaWeb()
On Error Resume Next
Dim endereço As String
Dim mostra As Boolean

Dim i, n, x As Integer
endereço = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-d6XfqSS_-P2SCRiIJMKU477NPlzFnkjVHe0RqO2DMSc4xA/viewform"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate (endereço)
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
IE.Visible = True

'Analista Argus
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(0).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(0).Value = "João"


'Detalhe Quantidade de ligações
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaPlaceholder exportLabel")(0).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea")(0).Value = "3"

'Com quem conseguiu contato
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaPlaceholder exportLabel")(1).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea")(1).Value = "joaozinho"

'Qual a tratativa dada pelo cliente
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaPlaceholder exportLabel")(2).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea")(2).Value = "nenhuma"


'Operação
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(1).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(1).Value = "ambev"

'Frota
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(2).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(2).Value = "fob4343"



'Tipo 1 Evento
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(18).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(18).Value = "sonolencia"


'Tipo 2 Evento
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(19).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(19).Value = "falso"

'Quantidade Evento tipo1
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(20).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(20).Value = "34"

'Quantidade Evento tipo 2
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(21).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(21).Value = "1"

'Indicador Intervenção
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(22).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(22).Value = "1,5"

   
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
End Sub
```